# Angular bootstrap modal how to call service from ok function of the modal?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented [Angular Bootstrap Modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal). Below is the angular code for it

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

this works fine.

My question is how do I use Services in the modal's controller ? In the ok function i want to make a service call and save some details and use the success and error callback.

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You simply inject your dependencies through controller constructor, i.e.:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, MyService) {

$scope.ok = function () {
    MyService.doSomething();
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};
```